# What does a .gbl file contain?

Tags: r, noaa, openair

I have to work in R with .gbl files. So far I'm using NOAA .gbl files, but I'm looking to generate my own.

I have been working with R openair and purr libraries. I know that I can use purr::walk() function to work with the files, but that still doesn't tell me what exactly do the files contain

Comment: HI, and welcome to Stack Overflow. At the moment your question is a bit vague. Can you please edit it to provide a concrete example of what _exactly_ you are trying to do, what you have attempted so far, and where you got stuck?

Comment: A file can have any extension you want so it's hard to really say anything about a file just based on the extension. Where are the files coming from exactly? Do they have any documentation on the file format? Also `purr::walk()` is just a generic iterator function. It's unclear how that function would ready any data on its one. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.